# Enqueue custom font file with rel="preload"

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, fonts

I'm using a custom font on my WP site. It is now included with `@font-face` css attribute. But I'm wondering if there is any way to `wp_enqueue` this file with the attribute `rel="preload"` and may be some other attributes. So it looks something like this in browser:

```
<link rel="preload" href="/fonts/custom-font-folder/CustomFontFile.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8):

You could try using the [style_loader_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/style_loader_tag/) filter.

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts');

function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('my-style-handle',
        '/fonts/custom-font-folder/CustomFontFile.woff2', array(), null);
}

add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'my_style_loader_tag_filter', 10, 2);

function my_style_loader_tag_filter($html, $handle) {
    if ($handle === 'my-style-handle') {
        return str_replace("rel='stylesheet'",
            "rel='preload' as='font' type='font/woff2' crossorigin='anonymous'", $html);
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Here we're enqueuing the stylesheet using the normal `wp_enqueue_style` function. We then capture the output using the filter and replace it's `rel` attribute with your updated attributes.

Comment: That works but you need to specify the number of arguments in add_filter:
`add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'my_style_loader_tag_filter', 10, 2);`